# Integrate struts2 application with rest API

Tags: java, rest, maven, struts2

I'm trying to implement a Rest interface for an existing struts2 application (migrating from webProject to Maven), making it work alongside the existing "action" calls.
I'm completely new to struts and maven, so I tried to follow this tutorial http://www.concretepage.com/struts-2/struts-2-rest-web-service-integration-example.
 The problem seems to be linked with the cohexistence in web.xml of the `<filter>` and `<servlet>` tags.
Here's the code

**the rest controller**

```java
package rest;

import csv.caiq.DataCaiq;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultHttpHeaders;
import org.apache.struts2.rest.HttpHeaders;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class CaiqController implements ModelDriven<Object> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String id;
    private Object model;
    private DataCaiq datacaiq = new DataCaiq();

    private static Map<String,String> map;
    {
        for (int i=0; i< datacaiq.getListCaiqs().size();i++)
        map.put(datacaiq.getListCaiqs().get(i).get(1),datacaiq.getListCaiqs().get(i).get(2));
    }

    public HttpHeaders index() {
        model = map;
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").disableCaching();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        return model;
    }    
}
```

Here's implemented only index() and getmodel() methods for testing purposes.

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
<display-name>Sl Evaluation</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>config</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest"/>
</struts>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SecurityReasoner</groupId>
<artifactId>SecurityReasoner</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
name>SecurityReasoner</name>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
     ......
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I receive error 404. If I delete the <filter> tag everything turns back fine, but I can't use the rest interface.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!The library commons-fileupload-1.1.1 was broken so i replaced it with commons-fileupload-1.2.2 and everithing works fine!